# Excel formula to find difference in time (minutes) - DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS

Tags: excel

Please help with a solution to find the time difference in minutes.
i am trying to find the time in minutes between two dates in the format -DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 1):

Assuming valid date/times in A2 and B2 you can get the difference (in days) with a simple subtraction, e.g.

`=B2-A2`

To convert that to minutes you multiply by the number of minutes in a day (1440), so this formula should do what you want

`=(B2-A2)*1440`

format result cell as number